# How to prevent signup again into a system

Tags: php, authentication

I have created a signup form and I want to prevent the same user signup to the system again and again. Here is my code and please help me to solve this problem. In the initial sign up only username password and email is considered and after signing to the system user can update their information such as name, gender, education etc:....

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'newFunctions.php';
include_once 'dbConnect.php';

// database connection
dbConnect(); 

$username = $_POST['username'];
$pw=md5($_POST['password']);
$email=$_POST['email'];

//check the term
if(isset($_POST['term'])){
    $is_checked = 1;
}else{
    $is_checked = 0;
}


$insert_data="INSERT INTO tutor(userName, password, email, avatar, term)
    VALUES
    ( '{$username}','{$pw}','{$email}','default_image.jpg','{$is_checked}')";


$check=mysql_query($insert_data);

if($check=='true')
{

// session variables
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
$_SESSION['username']=$username; 
$_SESSION['password']=$pw;

showAlert("You Have Successfully Registered ", "../tutor_panel_ui.php");

}

else{

echo "Invalid Login";

$_SESSION['login'] = '';
}

?>
```

Comment: create a unique index in the database for the field `email` and then your query it self will fail when you try to add a user who`s email already in the system.

Comment: and the field ``userName``, if you want

Comment: Can you explain more ? Actually what you want to do? whether you want to avoid the same user to sing up again with same user name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before

```
 $insert_data="INSERT INTO tutor(userName, password, email, avatar, term)
VALUES
( '{$username}','{$pw}','{$email}','default_image.jpg','{$is_checked}')";
```

you run a query to check if the email id or/and username already exist in your database.

it would be something like this

```
$query="SELECT userName (or/and) email FROM tutor WHERE email ='$email' (or/and) userName=$username ";
```

check if the result returned is empty or does it contains some rows.
If it is empty continue with registering the user otherwise tell the user that he has already reistered and he can not register again.

Comment: I like this for being able to be more specific with error messages although for successful logins it does "waste" one tinsy SQL query (okay that is microscopic but whatever)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:
set the tutor columns email and username to be each be a `UNIQUE KEY`.
and then I'd do the following edit of your code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'newFunctions.php';
include_once 'dbConnect.php';

// database connection
dbConnect(); 

$username = $_POST['username'];
$pw=md5($_POST['password']);
$email=$_POST['email'];

//check the term
if(isset($_POST['term'])){
    $is_checked = 1;
}else{
    $is_checked = 0;
}


$insert_data="INSERT INTO tutor(userName, password, email, avatar, term)
    VALUES
    ( '".mysql_real_escape_string({$username})."','".mysql_real_escape_string({$pw})."','{".mysql_real_escape_string($email})."','default_image.jpg','{$is_checked}')";


$check=mysql_query($insert_data);

if($check=='true')
{

// session variables
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
$_SESSION['username']=$username; 
$_SESSION['password']=$pw;

showAlert("You Have Successfully Registered ", "../tutor_panel_ui.php");
//showAlert is a javascript function - so unless you have defined it in your other files you'll need to do a different thing here.
}

else{

echo "Registration data invalid. Username and email must be unique. Are you already signed up and forgot your password? if so <a href='recoverpassword.php'>Recover your password</a>.";

$_SESSION['login'] = '';
}

?>
```

note: I put in `mysql_real_escape_string()` calls there to avoid horrible deadly SQL injection risks, but you should consider upgrading to PDO_ or mysqli_ instead of the mysql_ functions.